# Converting torch nn.mean to Tensorflow tf.reduce_mean

Tags: python, tensorflow

We have a tensor, a, of shape [batch, 27, 32, 32] in torch and of shape [batch, 32, 32, 27] in Tensorflow.
In Pytorch we do `a.mean(dim=(2,3), keepdim=True)` to get a tensor of shape [batch, 27, 1, 1].
When we try to do the same thing in Tensorflow  i.e., `tf.reduce_mean(a, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)`, and provided that the given tensor a have the same values, the output (the values) of these two functions are dissimilar.

Example: We have a tensor a. We perform the Tensorflow variant
output:

`[[[[0.447722971 0.353017896 0 ... 0.388245761 0 0.000387541251]]]]`

We have the same tensor a. We perform the Pytorch variant

```
[[[[0.0815329552]]  [[0.096422635]]  [[0.164515451]] ... [[0.207869291]] [[0.168954074][0.134754464]]]]
```

Why is that? How would one go about fixing it?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you sure your two tensors are the same? That `tensor_tf == np.moveaxis(tensor_torch,[0,1,2,3],[0,3,1,2])`?

Comment: @Lescurel In order to test we saved a pytorch tensor (a.npy), then loaded it back in tensorflow using np.load and finally converting it to a tensorflow tensor using convert_to_tensor (which gave us batch,27,32,32 in shape). We then reshaped this into its correct shape tf.reshape(a ,[batch, 32,32,27]) and did math_reduce mean on axis 1, 2. We also tried to not reshape the tensor and perform on the same axis as in pytorch, at which point the outputs were equal. Maybe the reshape is ambiguous?

Comment: Reshape is the completely wrong operation to do here. You should use [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose). Reshape will give you the right dimensions, but will reorder the element of the tensor in a different way than what you are looking after.

Comment: @Lescurel Thanks. I was under the, albeit wrong, notion that tensorflow would automagically re-order them correctly. But yes, it makes sense. Thanks :)